# Ruby on Rails - getting association data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many

I´m trying to make a User - Infos association where my User has_many Infos.

I´m trying to call my User Infos on the index form from Users.

By calling `<%= user.infos %>` on my index.html.erb (Users) it returns me all datas from the Infos table like this:

```
[#<Info id: 2, name: "Thales Miguel", date: "1989-07-14", area: "An\xC3\xA1lise de Sistemas", comment: "Analista j\xC3\xBAnior de sistemas.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-16 15:54:29", updated_at: "2012-01-16 15:54:29">]
```

I assumed that by doing `<%= user.infos.comment %>` it would return me the "comment" from that user, but all I get is this error:

```
undefined method `comment' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3b8ebe8>
```

What am I doing wrong?

infos_controller:

```
class InfosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @info = @user.infos.create(params[:info])
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @info = @user.infos.find(params[:id])
    @info.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_info    
end

end
```

info model:

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :login,    :presence => true
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :length   => {:minimum => 5}

  has_many :infos, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
[#<Info id: 2, name: "Thales Miguel", date: "1989-07-14", area: "An\xC3\xA1lise de Sistemas", comment: "Analista j\xC3\xBAnior de sistemas.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-16 15:54:29", updated_at: "2012-01-16 15:54:29">]
```

is an array. You have to choose one of the objects. You can't call an attribute value without selecting one of theses objects. Okay, in this case there is only one object but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, if you know there's just one (true in this case), call `user.infos.first`, or `user.infos.last`, or `user.infos[0]`. Whatever makes the most sense to you to pluck out only one object from the array. Google "ruby array" to find ruby documentation on the array class.

Comment: That does not looks "usual"...
What is the best way to do what I want?

How do I put then in objects?
You are REALLY helpping me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

So, collecting all info what written above:

You cannot call `user.infos.comment`, because the return value of `user.infos` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` in Rails 3.2 and an array in Rails 3.1 and below. Neither ActiveRecord::Relation nor array do not know what it should do with `comment` method because they don't know anything of the contained objects.

You have multiple solutions for solve this problem.

If user is limited to have only one info:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :info, :dependent => :destroy
end

<%= user.info.comment %>
```

If user can have multiple info objects:

```
<%- user.infos.each do |info| %>
<%= info.comment %>
<% end -%>
```

Or

```
<ul><li>
<%= user.infos.collect(&:comment).join('</li><li>').html_safe %>
</li></ul>
```

Or if you want to  display only the first info:

```
<%= user.infos.any? ? user.infos.first.comment : "N/A" %>
```

Be careful the latest solution: `user.infos` never be nil, but `user.infos.first` can be nil, so you must check available infos with `user.infos.any?`

Answer (score 1):

You should do this way:

```
<% user.infos.each do |info| %>
  <%= info.comment %>
<% end %>
```

As *davidb* said, `<% user.infos %>` returns an array. The object of `.comment` should be an instance.

Comment: This really works.
The problem is that, by doing this, I force the user to have infos.
Is there a way to not force it?

Comment: Try wrapping the above code with `<% unless user.infos.nil? %>` and `<% end %>`.

Comment: I tried the "unless user.infos.nil?" and it did not worked.
My code now is:

<% @users.each do |user| %>
      <% unless user.infos.nil? %>
       <% user.infos.each do |info| %>
         <tr>
       <td><%= user.login %></td>
       <td><%= user.password %></td>
       <td><%= info.name.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Detalhes', user %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Excluir', user, confirm: 'Tem certeza?', method: :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <% end %>

Comment: Hi, you put `<% unless user.infos.nil? %>` wrong place, it won't show anything if user.infos is nil. Try: `<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= user.login %></td>
  <td><%= user.password %></td>
  <% unless user.infos.nil? %>
    <% user.infos.each do |info| %>
    <td><%= info.name.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></td>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Detalhes', user %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Excluir', user, confirm: 'Tem certeza?', method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>`

Comment: With @Marco solution, you do not force user to have infos. if user has no infos, then `user.infos` returns with an empty array, and `each` does not execute passed block because no item for expanding inner variable.

Comment: Clarification: if no info assigned to the user, `user.infos` returns with an empty association.
If you still want to wrap your code, do not use `user.infos.nil?` what @Marco recommended, use `user.infos.any?` instead. In Rails 3.2, `user.infos` will never be nil, because it is always an ActiveRecord::Relation object, what _can_ return with an empty resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

> info is a relationship link

that returns an array of info records, if you want to show the first one for example

```
user.infos[0].comment
```

or

```
user.infos.first.comment
```

if that user don't have infos then return nil